# WPF ListView scroll from view model

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have observable collection called (Users) in view model that binded with ListViewControl (lstUsers) in view and what I need is to scroll to current logged in user in List View . 
I see in most of examples that used scroll from code behind  as following e.g. :

```
lstUsers.ScrollIntoView(lstUsers[5]);
```

but what I need is to handle it from view model .

Please advice !

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this would be to use something like an ICollectionView which has a current item. You can then set IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem to true to link the current item in the view model to the selected item in the ListView.

Finally handle the event SelectionChanged in the code behind the view to change the scroll position so that it always displays the selected item.

For me the benefit of this method is that the viewmodel is kept unaware of anything about the view which is one of the aims of MVVM. The code behind the view is the perfect place for any code concerning the view only.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView x:Name="View"
              SelectionChanged="Selector_OnSelectionChanged" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Command="{Binding ChangeSelectionCommand}">Set</Button>       
</Grid> 


public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }

    private void Selector_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        View.ScrollIntoView(View.SelectedItem);
    }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    private readonly CollectionViewSource _source = new CollectionViewSource();

    public ICollectionView Items
    {
        get { return _source.View; }
    }

    public ICommand ChangeSelectionCommand { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        SetUp();
        ChangeSelectionCommand = new Command(ChangeSelection);
    }

    private void SetUp()
    {
        var list = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            list.Add(i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        }
        _source.Source = list;
    }

    private void ChangeSelection()
    {
        var random = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

        var n = random.Next(100);

        Items.MoveCurrentToPosition(n);
    }
}

public class Command : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action _action;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _action();
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public Command(Action action)
    {
        _action = action;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

let me share my solution with you

1. Create your own ListView descendant with dependency property TargetListItem

   ```
   public class ScrollableListView : ListView
   {
       /// <summary>
       /// Set this property to make ListView scroll to it
       /// </summary>
       public object TargetListItem
       {
           get { return (object)GetValue(TargetListItemProperty); }
           set { SetValue(TargetListItemProperty, value); }
       }

       public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetListItemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
           nameof(TargetListItem), typeof(object), typeof(ScrollableListView), new PropertyMetadata(null, TargetListItemPropertyChangedCallback));

       static void TargetListItemPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
       {
           var owner = (ScrollableListView)d;
           owner.ScrollToItem(e.NewValue);
       }

       public void ScrollToItem(object value)
       {
           if (value != null && Items != null && Items.Contains(value))
           {
               ScrollIntoView(value);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. create property in ViewModel

   ```
   object currentListItem;
   public object СurrentListItem
   {
       get => сurrentListItem;
       set
       {
           if (сurrentListItem != value)
           {
               сurrentListItem = value;
               OnPropertyChanged(nameof(СurrentListItem));
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. bind it

   `<controls:ScrollableListView ... TargetListItem="{Binding CurrentListItem}"/>`

Now you can set CurrentListItem in ViewModel when needed. And the corresponding visual element will become visible in the ListView immediately.

Also maybe you just can use attached property on ListView instead of creating ScrollableListView. But i'm not sure.

Answer (score -1):

Yep, there's always times in MVVM when you need to get at the control.  There's various ways of doing this, but here's an easy-ish way of doing it without deriving from the control or messing with routed commands or other such toys what you have in WPF.

In summary:

- Create an attached property on your view model.
- Set the attached property in XAML to pass the list box back to the view model.
- Call .ScrollIntoView on demand.

Note, this is a rough and ready example, make sure your DataContext is set before showing the window.

Code/View Model:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private ListBox _listBox;

    private void ReceiveListBox(ListBox listBox)
    {
        _listBox = listBox;
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ListBoxHookProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "ListBoxHook", typeof (ListBox), typeof (ViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(default(ListBox), ListBoxHookPropertyChangedCallback));

    private static void ListBoxHookPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        var listBox = (ListBox) dependencyObject;
        var viewModel = (ViewModel) listBox.DataContext;
        viewModel.ReceiveListBox(listBox);
    }

    public static void SetListBoxHook(DependencyObject element, ListBox value)
    {
        element.SetValue(ListBoxHookProperty, value);
    }

    public static ListBox GetListBoxHook(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (ListBox) element.GetValue(ListBoxHookProperty);
    }
}
```

OK, so that will let us get the ListBox passed back to the view; you can do with it as you wish.

Now, just set the property in XAML:

```
<ListBox wpfApplication1:ViewModel.ListBoxHook="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
```

Good to go!

Comment: Yep, the answer daniellepelley gave is more MVVM than mine.